# How to set intent bundle extra when custom contact raw is clicked

Tags: android, android-intent, android-syncadapter

I created a contact sync adapter to connect with the users who are using my application (Just like how the whatsapp, viber is doing). I sync my contacts with the server to compare and get the users who are using the application. Then I get those user's list and add a custom row in the contact as in the below image.

[image: My sample Contact in the local phone book]

It opens my application once I click it. But I want to set the contact name and number (may be also the contact_id if possible) with the intent. I don't have any idea to achieve this task.

Here is how I'm adding the new contact raw.

```
public  void addAccount(String displayName, String phone, Context context) {
    if (context == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(displayName) || TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) return;

    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> providerOperations = new ArrayList<>();

    // add the account type
    providerOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.example.myapp")
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.example.myapp")
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE,
                    ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DEFAULT)
            .build());

    // create a new raw contact in the table
    providerOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName)
            .build());

    // add the custom action and the mime type
    providerOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, context.getString(R.string.contact_mime_type))
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, phone)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, displayName)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "Message (" + phone + ")") // the new list item shown in the contact
            .build());

    try {
        // add all the provider operations
        resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, providerOperations);
        Log.i(TAG, "account added for contact - '" + displayName + "'");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

authenticator.xml

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountPreferences="@xml/account_preferences"
android:accountType="com.example.myapp"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:smallIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
```

contacts.xml

```
<ContactsSource xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ContactsDataKind
    android:detailColumn="data3"
    android:detailSocialSummary="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/com.example.myapp"
    android:summaryColumn="data2" />
```

sync_contacts.xml

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountType="com.example.myapp"
android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
android:supportsUploading="true"
android:userVisible="true" />
```

manifest-

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:resizeableActivity="false"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsPictureInPicture="false"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/com.example.myapp" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".sync.ContactsSyncAdapterService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":contacts">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/sync_contacts" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.provider.CONTACTS_STRUCTURE"
            android:resource="@xml/contacts" />
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".sync.AuthenticatorService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":auth">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>

</application>
```

Finally, when I print the intent action in my `SplashScreenActivity` - `onCreate` method, it shows `android.intent.action.VIEW` on a contact action click launch and  `android.intent.action.MAIN` on normal application launch.

Comment: so what `"intent extra"` are you talking about in the title?

Comment: Bundle extra. you know. I want to get the contact name and number from  the `SplashScreenActivty` to navigate them to the correct chat thread.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution for this. We can get the contact's content URI from the Viewing Intent. 
And the we can get access the contact from the content URI.

```
private void getContactFromUri() {
    String dataString = getIntent().getDataString();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(dataString);
    String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
            null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String name = cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String number = cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            cursor.close();
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```